# Making primitive data types readOnly/nonConfig in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties, readonly

Does anyone have any example implementation of making individual object props readOnly/non-configurable? I mean primitive data types. Have tried using ES5 Object API, but hitting a brick wall.

I can't show code, because it's still at that "messy" phase, but basically I'm iterating through an outside object which, itself, holds numeruos objects. Those objects each hold various primitive data types. I have made the outer objects readOnly, non-config, etc, but can't figure out how to do likewise for individual props, the innermost props.

So, if `outer.inner.prop === "Hello"`, I want to make that value `readOnly`.

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

I just figured this out, it was all in the for loop I was using to iterate over props. Now I've actually get data descriptors for the props, even the primitive ones. :) Thanks all!

Comment: What about defining a setter that doesn't set the property?

Comment: one thing you need to understand is that instances of String, Boolean, and Number, are *not* "primitive data types" - they're objects. What you're talking about, I think (though your question is not really clear) are primitive *values* like string, numeric, and boolean values referenced by object properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through the inner object, since there is no way to deep-freeze an object using standard ES5 methods.

```
function deepFreeze(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'object')
            deepFreeze(obj[key]);
    });
    Object.freeze(obj);
}
```

**Edit:**
Also works for `defineProperty` if you don't want to `freeze`:

```
function deepWriteProtect(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == 'object')
            deepWriteProtect(obj[key]);
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, { writable: false });
    });
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, deep freezing would be acceptable, but it wouldn't freeze up primitive data types, String, Boolean, etc. My innermost objects contain these types, and I need to get at their data descriptors.

Comment: yeah when I set a property to writable:false, and the property points to a primitive, I can still mutate that property, AFAICT

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question correctly, but from what I gather you are asking for private variables. If so, that can be easily achieved using closures.

```
function myClass(){
    var mySecretProperty = 10;
    this.getMySecretProperty = function(){
         return mySecretProperty;
    }
    this.changeMySecretProperty = function(s){
         // whatever logic you need for a setter method
         mySecretProperty = s;
    }
}

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.changeMySecretProperty(120);
myObj.getMySecretProperty(); // will return 120
myObj.mySecretProperty // will return undefined
```

Comment: Closures would've been my first choice, but I use the object internally, and since my writable ref to the object is in the same scope as user defined callbacks, the user could alter it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following (ES5) example help? It creates an empty constructor, with a getter for property `a` (and no setter, so de facto `a` is read only):

```
var Obj = function(){};
Obj.prototype = {
    get a() {return 5;}
}
var x = new Obj;
alert(x.a); //=> 5
x.a = 6; //=> TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter
```

Not using ES5 you can do

```
var Obj = function(){
  var a = 5;
  if (!Obj.prototype.getA) {
     Obj.prototype.getA = {
         toString: function() {
            return a;
         }
     };
  }
}

var y = new Obj;
alert(y.getA); //=> 5
```

But that is not 100% failsafe: `Obj.prototype.getA` can be overwritten.

Comment: Well, I am doing that but I'm using the get fn(){} syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7k7b/1/) is a jsfiddle showing how you  can use ES5 getter/setter definitions to make a property of an object something that can only be fetched.  The code looks like this:

```
var object = {
    get x() {
        return 17;
    }, set x() {
        alert("You cannot set x!");
    }
};
```

Of course the getter could obtain the value of the property ("x") from anywhere, like a closure from a constructor or something.  The point is that the setter simply does not change the value, so attempts to change it:

```
object.x = 100;
```

will not have any effect.

Comment: Hi, Pointy. I was already using closures, but scope issues meant they didn't work for my purposes, and I am currently using the get fn(){} syntax for safely retrieving object. :) Thanks for answering! I actually figured out what my problem was. It is possible to use Object API from ES5 on primitive types, but my for loops were wrong (whoops!)... Got it working now. :D Thanks!